# Magento: skip frontend cookie session

Tags: magento, session-cookies

I have a question that does magento work with a browser cookie disabled.

I know that magento must set cookies for login / add product to cart actions.

Is there any module or way to avoid working with cookies.

Cheers,

k

Comment: If you want to display the website as just a catalog, it is possible. If you mean to have full possibilities of webstore, I do not think so.

Comment: yup, magento site really rely on cookie stuff after I do some research..